# mod_wsgi and django deployment

Tags: python, django, wsgi, apache

I have mod_wsgi installed and everything works on my development server. I am running centos and cant seem to figure out what to add to my httpd.conf. Is the mysite.com like my main url that I am going to be sending requests from? so should `/path/to/mysite.com` be `/home/dbs/www`? Lets assume my main domain is hello.com and is located at `/home/dbs/www`
My wsgi.py path is correct.

this is what I have so far

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pycode/main/main/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should go watch:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

as an introduction and explanation of common problems.

It does not cover the specifics though of how particular Linux distros reorganise the Apache configuration files compare to official Apache Software Foundation layout.

Also, the presentation covers Django as configuration was done before 1.4. The general layout you have above is for Django 1.4 and so you will need to adjust what is covered in presentation to newer Django 1.4 way of doing things.